# Ubuntu won't see external usb 3.0 drive

Tags: usb, usb-drive

I have a Lenovo e31-70 running Ubuntu 16.04 and when I plug the external drive it doesn't see it at all. `dmesg` gives this

```
[   59.819492] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: port 1 resume PLC timeout
[   63.354561] usb usb3-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[   64.431480] usb 3-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[   64.448321] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=1153
[   64.448324] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[   64.448326] usb 3-2: Product: AS2115
[   64.448328] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: ASMedia
[   64.448330] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 00000000000000000000
[   64.448992] usb-storage 3-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   64.449763] scsi host2: usb-storage 3-2:1.0
[   64.786469] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[   65.025964] usb 3-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[   70.033750] usb 3-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[   70.137415] usb 3-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[   75.149068] usb 3-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[   75.420908] usb 3-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[   80.434109] usb 3-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[   80.537971] usb 3-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[   85.550329] usb 3-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[   85.825648] usb 3-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[   86.029411] usb 3-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[   86.229885] usb 3-2: device not accepting address 7, error -71
[   86.545762] usb 3-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[   86.562767] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=1153
[   86.562771] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[   86.562773] usb 3-2: Product: AS2115
[   86.562775] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: ASMedia
[   86.562776] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 00000000000000000000
[   86.563436] usb-storage 3-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   86.563564] scsi host3: usb-storage 3-2:1.0
[   86.749532] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 8
```

Anyone can  help ?

Comment: It might be that the USB 3.0 port does not provide enough power for your external drive or the controllers are not compatible. In both cases you could try to connect the external drive via an USB hub, which should have an external power supply to provide more power on the USB bus.

Comment: It says "`Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?`". Have you tried replacing the USB cable?

Comment: I would try and use the SMART tools found in the `Disks` application to see if you've got a drive problem.

Comment: Tested with a usb hub with external power supply and it's working.Thanks everybody for your answers!

Comment: Although we sometimes close questions as "a problem that can't be reproduced" that turn out to be hardware problems, that's usually because they can't be diagnosed or fixed based on the information available in Ubuntu, or because it's unclear what, if anything, made them go away. Neither applies in this situation, so rather than voting to close this question, I'll post a CW answer incorporating information from the comments.

Answer (score 4):

This was answered [in a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/856527/ubuntu-wont-see-external-usb-3-0-drive/1250015#comment1319123_856527) by [Thomas](https://askubuntu.com/users/490838/thomas):

> It might be that the USB 3.0 port does not provide enough power for your external drive or the controllers are not compatible. In both cases you could try to connect the external drive via an USB hub, which should have an external power supply to provide more power on the USB bus.

– [Thomas](https://askubuntu.com/users/490838/thomas) [Dec 3 '16 at 13:44](https://askubuntu.com/questions/856527/ubuntu-wont-see-external-usb-3-0-drive/1250015#comment1319123_856527)

When `dmesg` outputs messages like "device descriptor read/8, error -110", this usually means there is a hardware problem. As [waltinator](https://askubuntu.com/users/25618/waltinator) [pointed out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/856527/ubuntu-wont-see-external-usb-3-0-drive#comment1319148_856527), this particular set of messages had the more specific suggestion, "Maybe the USB cable is bad?"

The Linux kernel cannot typically distinguish between a bad USB cable and other problems preventing power or data from being transmitted. Besides the cable, it is in general worth checking the connections and ensuring the device is adequately powered.

[You found that using a powered hub fixed the problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/856527/ubuntu-wont-see-external-usb-3-0-drive#comment1319370_856527), which makes sense given the error messages. Future readers who see similar messages would be well served to try this, as well as to consider other hardware problems (some of them easily fixable) that might interfere with data or power.